# custom DB based security authorization model for glassfish

Tags: security, glassfish, authorization

we need to a highly customized security system for our JSF project.

our security system's requirements are as follow:

1-the system must control the access to any URLs

2-the system must control the access to any action

3-the system has many users and each user has different access
(i mean we are unable to define general roles)

4-we want to store all security settings in DB

5-setting must be dynamic ( no redeploy is necessary for changing setting)

i could not find any useful model or document for designing and implementing such system.
any helps and general guidelines appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit brief, but if I understand it correctly then [Oracle Access Manager](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/identity-management/oracle-access-manager/overview/index.html) may be able to help you.